# List Element and javascript values

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm trying to create a list and append values to it that I've retrieved from xml http request.  I've tested just a text block with the value of `typeAssetProcess` and it prints fine, but when I start trying to use a list is when everything starts to break. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "../controls" as Controls
Item {

Column {
    id: column

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
}

ListView {
    id: listView

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            name: qstr("Proccess: %1").arg(typeAssetProcess)
            colorCode: "grey"
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "Red"
            colorCode: "red"
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "Blue"
            colorCode: "blue"
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "Green"
            colorCode: "green"
        }
    }
    delegate: Item {
        x: 5
        width: 80
        height: 40
        Row {
            id: row1
            Rectangle {
                width: 40
                height: 40
                color: colorCode
            }

            Text {
                text: name
                font.bold: true
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            spacing: 10
        }
    }
}

}
```

This code is what is breaking:

```
ListElement {
    name: qstr("Proccess: %1").arg(typeAssetProcess)
    colorCode: "grey"
}
```

Comment: what is `typeAssetProcess`, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation to the [`ListElement`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html) type, containing a "collection of *role* definitions instead of properties". This is why you can not use script or property binding for these roles (otherwise you get the error `ListElement: cannot use script for property value`).

Improvements are frequently requested to the Qt team but as far as I know there is no implementation yet.

One thing you can do is dynamically initialize the model instead of using fixed `ListElement`:

```
ListView {
    id: listView

    readonly property var modelElements: [
        {
            name: qsTr("Proccess: %1").arg(typeAssetProcess),
            colorCode: "grey"
        },
        {
            name: "Red",
            colorCode: "red"
        },
        {
            name: "blue",
            colorCode: "blue"
        },
        {
            name: "Green",
            colorCode: "green"
        }]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        modelElements.forEach(function(element) {
            model.append(element)
        })
    }

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    model: ListModel {}
    delegate: ...
}
```

You can also choose to implement your own model in C++.